# Reading a potentiometer on MCU

Tags: microcontroller, current, potentiometer

I want to read a voltage of 3.3V on my MCU's ADC input.
I have a potentiometer that is to provide some feedback. I am wondering if it is necessary to add the R1 resistor, I added it since my MCU has a current limit of 8mA for GPIO, although I think this pin won't draw current but only read the voltage?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTEmHo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: 8mA is the maximum rating for output current from a GPIO pin, not input current.

Comment: "The GPIOs (general purpose input/outputs) can sink or source up to ±8 mA"

Comment: Both "sink" and "source" are outputs. The only difference is which direction the current flows.

Comment: So essentially, that voltage divider would work to read a value of around 1.65V max?

Comment: No, you don't need R1.  However the value of R2 is a bit small, so it will draw more current than likely necessary.  Were the MCU pin to accidentally be configured as an output so that it is fighting the potentiometer, at some extreme of the potentiometer setting the current specification could be exceeded.  If you want to protect against that, place a series resistor between the wiper of R2 and the MCU. However be careful that the series resistor is small in comparison to the effective ADC input impedance *in the selected mode of operation* (which can sometimes be rather low).

Comment: How well (to within what percent( do you need to know the wiper position, and what is the resolution of the ADC?

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you don't need R1.  In fact, you can't have R1 if you want the output to go all the way to 3.3 V.

   100 Ω is way too little.  That will draw 33 mA just sitting there doing nothing.  That could well be more than the processor.

   The 8 mA figure applies to how much the pin can source or sink when configured as a output.  This has nothing to do with using it as a A/D input.

Use a 10 kΩ or so pot directly across 3.3 V to ground.  This is assuming that the A/D also uses the 3.3 V supply as its high end reference.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before with a 5 volt PIC MPU. 1K potentiometers work the best. They keep the impedance low and you can connect directly to the 3.3 volt source.

To filter out wiper noise I would add a 100nF capacitor to the analog input of the MPU. If you insert a 100 ohm resistor in series with the input pin then have the filter capacitor you also limit noise transients from the Vcc line.

You will have to take care of 'scaling' the 0 to 3.3 volt range internally as software. If you have a 10 bit ADC you have a range of 000 to 999 (1024 rounded to math.floor).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a 10-bit ADC with a 0-3.3V range, your ADC has a 3mV resolution.  The range of possible values for your wiper voltage is 1.65V, which would span about 512 values on your ADC.  Allowing a bit for noise, say, you'd probably be able to effectively differentiate about 256 values.  It's about 1/3 worse on a 5V ADC.  If this is good enough performance for you, you're good to go.

If it's not good enough, you can toss R1, if you don't care about the 33mA of current you need for the circuit  If you do, just use a potentiometer with a higher resistance.

You can read up on what impendances your particular ADC can deal with.  In any case, it shouldn't suck much current.  I believe charge time of your sample and hold starts to kick in, though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you may want to consider:

**Current draw**

ADC inputs are usually high impedance. So you dont need to worry about the input current on this pin and can therefore drop R1 as a current limiter.

However, current will constantly flow through your potentiometer.
If you use 100 Ohms only, the current will be I= U/R = 33mA. Depending on the circuit this is quite a lot. You could go with a 10k potentiometer instead.

**Input voltage range**

Usually, the ADC value is scaled. The input voltage is compared to some reference voltage (that may only be 1.0V for your MCU, please check the datasheet), and the result you get is basically Vin/Vref*2^NumberOfBits. So make sure Vin is smaller than Vref (to both get useful results and not damage the ADC).

In order to achieve this, your R1 may be replaced by another resistor that is meant as a voltage devider instead of current limiting.

Make sure that the votlage drop over the potentiometer you select will not exceed reference/max input voltage of your ADC.